# Convert WORD to string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to send a CAN message using WiFi.

The message is composed of a 2 byte ID (WORD) and a 8 byte data field (QWORD).

I have to write the packet to the WiFi chip using UART so I want to convert the WORD and QWORD to a string and then use putsUART to send it.

How can I convert those variables to a string?

Struct of the WiFi packet:

```
typedef struct {
    WORD id;
    QWORD data;
} WiFiTXPacket;
```

Comment: What does text have to do with anything? CAN refers to controller-area network, the automotive wire protocol?

Comment: By the way, to convert several numbers to a string (WORD and QWORD are just numbers), you can use `printf`. Use `scanf` to convert back. But something is pretty fishy here.

Comment: Controller-Area-Network, yes. I need a string to feed it to the WiFi chip.

Comment: Why do you need a string? Again, what does text have to do with anything? WiFi (Ethernet) isn't a text protocol.

Comment: i still dont understand what do you mean by **string**. Is it an `ASCII` representation of numbers in packet or stream of bytes from packet ?

Comment: I'm using a Roving RN-131 WiFi chip which assembles the WiFi packet itself if I just pass it data using UART. The data coming from CAN are bytes which are stored in the WiFiTXPacket. Afterwards (to send the packet) I get the ID and Data out and parse them to a string to send using putsUART (which sends strings).

Comment: Since both the CAN address and data fields can contain null bytes, it is not possible to transfer them as C-style strings.

Comment: Well, not directly, anyway.  What protocol is expected by the WiFi interface?

Comment: No protocol at all. You just feed it any data and it will encapsulate it in a TCP frame and send it.
I think I fixed it sending byte by byte and shifting the bits.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
char package[10];
memcpy (&package, &wifiPackage, sizeof (WiFiTXPacket));

putsUART(package, strlen(package)); // i dont know how this function looks like, but for example ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("id: %hu  data: %llu \n", id, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *package = (char *)&wifiPackage;
putsUART(package, sizeof (WiFiTXPacket));
```

Depend on Gossamer's answer. I think it could be like this.
if use memcpy function. and calculate with strlen(packeage). if there any zero value. may cause problem happened!